# C# application locks files after accessing them

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been searching for some time and I haven't found an answer to this, so I thought I'd ask instead and sorry if it infact has been asked already :)

I've been trying to create a small program that helps one of our people in another department, and while the program runs quite fine, I find myself unable to delete, move or write to files that have been accessed by the program for as long as the program runs.

I let him create simple configurations for calculations he needs to make, but I can't let him remove or edit configuration the program has already loaded in.

The code I have which accesses the files

```
configs = new List<Config>();
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.csv"))
{
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName);
    Config currentConfig = new Config(file.Name);
    Code runs here...
}
```

The Config class is a simple class I've created and it holds information from the csv's that's loaded in

The rest of the code doesn't touch the files.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You aren't disposing your reader.  Put it in a using block.

Comment: As @LarsTech said. either dispose or put the `StreamReader` into a using

Comment: @LarsTech Hah! That worked. Thank you! I've been staring myself blind at this :)

Franck  I tried disposing, but that didn't work.

Comment: What is `Config`? It looks like it is also reading from a file.. What do you do with `reader`?

Comment: @Jeroen Config is a class I've created to hold the data in the files I read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others has pointed out, you should use `using` statement ([MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)) but I would like to explain the 'why part' a little bit.

The reason behind this is a fact, that you open a file, read it and *keep it open*. I love C# for its garbage collection, but in this case it doesn't kicks in by itself. You have to dispose of `Streams` (and other `IDisposable` objects) yourself. You can do this by a) calling `reader.Close()` and `reader.Dispose()` when done with file, or b) let C# do it for you by using the `using` statement as

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName)) {
    //Do your stuff
}
```

What happens here is when program exits `using` statement the `reader` is disposed of by the "end" of `using` statement. This is also true in a case of throwing Exceptions, what the the first case does not handle. In a practice `using` it behaves as a `try { ... } finally { ... }` block of sorts.

Comment: And here I've been told C# GC collects everything :)

Comment: @aSnejbjerg - it will but eventually. It is your job as the writer of the code to ensure that `Dispose` is called on instances where the type implements `IDipsoable` as those types generally access external resources like files, memory, database connections, etc. and preferable you want to release those resources as soon as they are no longer needed instead of waiting for garbage collection to happen.

Comment: @aSnejbjerg Well, it kind-of does, but as @Igor points out, you have to tell GC that it is fine to clean this object now and that it does not need to wait until closure of program. And you do this by calling `Dispose()`. ;-)

Comment: Or better, you can let the C# call `Dispose()` for you by using the `using`. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the information - This helps quite a bit in general aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use 'using' block

```
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.csv"))
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
    {
         Config currentConfig = new Config(file.Name);
         // Code runs here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to Close an Dispose your StreamReader:

```
configs = new List<Config>();
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.csv"))
{
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
    {
        Config currentConfig = new Config(file.Name);
        Code runs here...
    } // reader will be disposed here
}
```

Comment: @aSnejbjerg whats the difference between the other answer?

Comment: I was just too quick to dismiss this because you said dispose - They are the same.

Comment: daniell89 was 16 seconds faster :D